# I need to change the style of anchor tag in my div only and use different styles for other divs

Tags: html, css

I want to change the style for my anchor tag in a div using css but the code will select all anchor tags in the html code

```css
.links a:link,
{
  background-color: #ffbe58;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 21px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px
}


}
.links a:visited {
  background-color: #ffbe58;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 21px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px
}
.links a:hover {
  background-color: #4ca494;
  border-radius: 25px
}
.links a:active {
  background-color: #4ca494;
  border-radius: 25px
}
```

the should change style for `<a>` tag included in `<div>` tag only

Edit: here's the HTML part of this

```
                                    <b>
                                        <a href="Tech.html" style="display:inline-block"> Tech </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
                                        <a href="Gaming.html" style="display:inline-block" > Gaming </a>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <a href="Sports.html" style="display:inline-block"> Sports</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <a href="Stocks.html" style="display:inline-block"> Stocks </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <a href="Feedback.html" style="display:inline-block"> Feedback </a>

                                    </b>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML code also?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're asking, you can assign that specific anchor tag an id and refer to that in the css. Or if you want all in one div, assign that div and id and refer to that in the css. Ex:

```html
<div id="mydiv"><a href="someurl"></a></div>
```

```css
#mydiv a {
/* your style */
}
```

Comment: the problem with that is that the hyperlinks have different states and i wish to style them in a manner that only applies to the <a> tags in the specific <div>, my html is done properly, its the css that im having a tough time with

Answer (score 0):

Give class name to your anchor tag:

```
<div class="links">
  <a class="myclassname" href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

And in CSS, select your link and change style:

```
.links a.myclassname{
background: #ffbe58;
}
```